# Call function with parameter in its name

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hello I'm using laravel 4. I want to know how to call function like :

`$model->trans('name'), $model->trans('title')`

as

`$model->transName(), $model->transTitle()`

So this mean I want to call function trans with parameter `name,or title`, but the function name and parameter are attached.

It's like Eloquent when we do something like this : `whereEmail(), whereId()`.

I hope this makes a sense.

Thank you

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense, but its not a problem as long as you can call functions in php just like a string. `function trans($field) { $function = 'trans' . $field; $function(); }`

Comment: If you don't want to create `trans function` - check out __call magic method - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: but actually it only means poor application design

Comment: What do you mean by ` poor application design?,  it is means this method is not goo ?

Comment: I mean if you need to do something like you've described in your question probably you went wrong somewhere. Can are you explain, what you trying to do?

Comment: I just liked this way it is so clean and simple to use.

Comment: Once again, can you explain what you trying to do? After you call `$model->transName()` what it will return?

Comment: It will return the translation of the attribute in param from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you sure that you need it, here is working example using magic method

```
<?php

class Model 
{
    public function __call($func, $args)
    {           
        if(strstr($func, 'trans'))
        {
            return $this->trans(strtolower(str_replace('trans', '', $func)));
        }

       return parent::__call($func, $args);
    }

    public function trans($field)
    {
        return $field;
    }
}

$m = new Model();

$m->transSomething();
```

When undefined method will be called, it will check if method name starts with 'trans', and if so pass it to `$this->trans()` without "trans" at beginning.

But in my opinion the way with `$model->trans('somefield')` is better.

Comment: Comment: I get some methods call issue like : `Call to a member function inLanguage() on a non-object` when I use __call in the model, have you any idea ?

Comment: I modified the example, try it now.

Comment: I modified also the code, and now it works :). Thank you a lot